# Problema con codigo php error array to string conversion y undefined index

Tags: php

al hacer una consulta de sql y recorrerla me da error

```
    function informe_stock_critico(){
$faltante=0;
$item="";
$total=0;
$subtotal=0;
$sql="SELECT count(CODIGO_PRODUCTO) AS subtotal,p.ID_CATEGORIA, NOMBRE_CATEGORIA from categorias c, producto p where c.ID_CATEGORIA=p.ID_CATEGORIA
 and STOCK_REAL<=STOCK_MINIMO GROUP BY p.ID_CATEGORIA";
$resultado=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql);
while ($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
 $id=$datos["ID_CATEGORIA"];
 $categoria=$datos["NOMBRE_CATEGORIA"];
 $subtotal=$datos["subtotal"];

    $sql2="SELECT CODIGO_PRODUCTO AS codigo,DESCRIPCION AS  descripcion, STOCK_MAXIMO ,STOCK_MINIMO, p.RUT_PRO AS rut,pro.RAZON_SOCIAL As razon
      FROM categorias c, producto p, proveedor pro     
           WHERE c.ID_CATEGORIA = p.ID_CATEGORIA
           AND STOCK_REAL <= STOCK_MINIMO
           AND pro.RUT_PRO = p.RUT_PRO
           AND p.ID_CATEGORIA='$id'";
$resultado2=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql2);
// $fila=mysqli_num_rows($resultado2);
while ($datos2=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)) {
  $codigo=$datos2=["codigo"];
  $descripcion=$datos2["descripcion"];
  $stock_max=$datos2["STOCK_MAXIMO"];
  $stock_min=$datos2["STOCK_MINIMO"];
  $rut=$datos2["rut"];
  $nombre=$datos2["razon"];
  $faltante=$stock_max-$stock_min;
  $tabla.="<tr>
     <td>$codigo</td>
     <td>$descripcion</td>
      <td>$faltante</td>
      <td>$rut</td>
      <td>$$nombre</td>
    </tr>";

  }
  $fila=mysqli_num_rows($resultado2);
  if ($fila>=1) {
    $item.=$tabla."<tr><td colspan='3'>Total  $categoria  : $subtotal</td> </tr>";
  }
  $total=$total+$subtotal;
}
return $item."<tr><td colspan='3'>Total  productos  : $total</td> </tr>";
```

}

me da estos errores[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que esos campos existen para las tablas correspondientes?

Comment: si hice la consulta en phpmyadmin y trae esos campos

Comment: como? declararla arriba

Comment: he eliminado la respuesta... me he confundido.... lo que te dije estaba bien de las constantes pero en tu caso no son constantes....

Comment: defini las constantes y ahora no hay errores pero no trae nada la consulta

Comment: creo que es un problema con el while o algo

Comment: no sabes que mas puede ser que este causando el error

Comment: Yo en tu lugar cambiaria también los nombres de la base de datos en minúscula...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La línea `$codigo=$datos2=["codigo"];` está sobreescribiendo la variable `$datos2` que al principio del `while` contenía el array con los campos del registro del resultado de la consulta, pero luego de esa línea, `$datos2` sólo contiene `["codigo"]`.

No entiendo el propósito de esa línea, pero empezando por comentarla, deberías solucionar los errores mencionados.

Luego, ver cual era la intención original de esa línea y modificarla.

Comment: muchas gracias tienes razon no me habia fijado bien .